# Deleting/Hiding a column of a table in PySimpleGui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I got a table in PySimpleGui (sg.Table) and I want to add the option to hide/delete a column of that table. I found a way to do this with the data of the table, but it seems you can't edit the headings of a table on the fly. At least the `.update()` method doesn't provide one.

My first thought: Creating a new window with new data, without that column. But that seems like a laborious way of doing things...

Is there any clever way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure ttk.Treeview (sg.Table) with option `displaycolumns` to select which columns are actually displayed and determines the order of their presentation. Add one more `'Row'` before your displaycolumns list if you specified `display_row_numbers=True`.

```py
from copy import deepcopy
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")

newlist = [
    [f"Cell ({row:0>2d}, {col:0>2d})" for col in range(8)]
        for row in range(10)
]

COL_HEADINGS = ["Date", "Ref", "ID", "Owner", "Customer", "Price", "Size", "Path"]

layout = [
    [sg.Table(
        values=newlist,
        headings=COL_HEADINGS,
        max_col_width=25,
        num_rows=10,
        alternating_row_color='green',
        display_row_numbers=True,
        key='-TABLE-',
        enable_click_events=True,
        justification='center',
    )],
    [sg.Button('Hide Customer')],
]

window = sg.Window('Table', layout, finalize=True)
table = window['-TABLE-']

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Hide Customer':
        window[event].update(disabled=True)
        displaycolumns = deepcopy(COL_HEADINGS)
        displaycolumns.remove('Customer')
        table.ColumnsToDisplay = displaycolumns
        table.Widget.configure(displaycolumns=['Row']+displaycolumns)

window.close()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!
One more thing: If I use row numbers (`display_row_numbers=True`) and use your solution, the row numbers disappear. Do you know why? Or have a solution for this?

Comment: Update as above.